# Selecting latest workout set by user

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm trying to select the latest added workout set associated with a given user.

Users has sessions and sessions has sets. My entities are defined as below.

```
            @Entity(name = "users") // Postgres doesn't like the table name "user"
            public class User {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
                private Set<Session> sessions;
            ...

            @Entity
            public class Session {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                @ManyToOne
                private User user;
                @OneToMany(mappedBy = "session")
                private Set<WorkoutSet> sets;
            ...

            @Entity
            public class WorkoutSet {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                @OneToOne
                private User user;
                @ManyToOne
                private Session session;
                private LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
            ...
```

The following sql query seems to do the trick

```
select w
from workout_set w
  inner join session s
  on w.session_id = s.id
where s.user_id = 1
order by w.timestamp DESC
limit 1
```

But when I'm trying to do something like the below

```
            @Repository
            public interface WorkoutSetRepository extends CrudRepository<WorkoutSet, Long> {
                @Query("select w from WorkoutSet w inner join Session s on w.session_id = s.id where s.user = :user order by w.timestamp")
                List<WorkoutSet> findLastSet(User user, Pageable limit);
```

I get...

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property user found for type WorkoutSet!
```

Any clues about how to do the query right? I'm very open to alternative ways as well because I'd rather avoid writing jpql if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkoutSetRepository extends CrudRepository<WorkoutSet, Long> {
    @Query("select w from WorkoutSet w inner join w.session s where s.user = :user order by w.timestamp")
    List<WorkoutSet> findLastSet(@Param("user") TestUser user);
}
```

Note the difference in the join clause. This works with hibernate 5.0.11.